# Unity cannot find Android SDK on Windows

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine

I installed Android Studio (3.6.2) along with Android SDK, but when I choose its folder in Unity (Edit -> Preferences -> External Tools), it says "Unable to detect SDK in the selected directory." What do I have to do to make it work? I use Unity 2018.4 (LTS) on Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

Unity seems to have trouble with folder structure of SDK installed with Android Studio. It seems it expects command line tools to contain folder called `tools`, but Android Studio stores those in `cmdline-tools\latest`. Assuming the SDK is installed in `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk` you have to do the following:

- Copy folder `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools\latest` to `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\`
- Rename `latest` to `tools`

In the end you should have a folder called `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools` present. It should contain `bin` and `lib` folders. When you choose `Sdk` folder in Unity, it processes it and you should be able to build Android apk.

I have no idea if this is the right approach, but we were able to make Android builds work on Windows following these steps.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this post while searching, and through I would post my solution.

1. Confirm that Virtualization is enabled in your BIOS.
2. Uninstall both Android Studio and Unity Editor
3. Install Android Studio First, then Unity Editor and build targets
4. Delete the Library folder from your project
5. Launch the project, then give it a shot